# Google Sheet Apps Script to automatically duplicate a template and rename for the date

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have to go into a number of different workbooks daily, duplicate a master, and rename it for the current date and hide past dates. Is there a script to do that automatically? If so, is there anything that I can add so that it hides all other sheets so only the sheet with the previous date and current date is visible? I need it to rename the sheets with the month and the date ex. "Jan. 24". I know absolutely nothing about Apps Script, If I can get something I can just copy and paste that would be amazing. Thank you in advance!